# Can JSONP services handle large parameters?

Tags: jsonp

I have an application that needs to send a large data structure back and forth between the client web browser and a server hosting a WCF service. The data structure is basically a tree, where the nodes in the tree, in their serialized form, can be about a kilobyte each, and there can be as many as a few hundred of these nodes in a call.

The application is legacy and written with JSONP to support cross-domain support. I cannot replace JSONP given the schedule constraints of the project.

Ideally I'd pass the serialized data in the HTTP request body, but as I google the intertubes, I'm learning that JSONP requests are HTTP GET only -- so no request body. This also means that I run into the limitations of HTTP GET: query strings cannot reliably be longer than 8 kilobytes or so.

My intention is avoid the need to save state on the WCF service, by having the client send a modified tree to the server, the server then validates the tree, performs related tree operations if needed, and then sends the modified tree back to the client in the response for updating the UI. Is this feasible if the data being roundtripped is on the order of 100 kbytes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to solve JSONP size limitations (HTTP GET url/querystring limits) is to break up large requests into multiple smaller requests, but to do this you 'need' some sort of state (session, temporary cache) on the server side.

```
CLIENT /jsonp?part=1&of=3&callback=foobar&datachunk=...
SERVER foobar("part 1 received");
CLIENT /jsonp?part=3&of=3&callback=foobar&datachunk=...
SERVER foobar("part 3 received");
CLIENT /jsonp?part=2&of=3&callback=foobar&datachunk=...
SERVER foobar("all parts received heres the result");
```

**EDIT** Here's another possibility if you want to send just 2 requessts. Use AJAX on the client to POST the large data to the server. The server will cache the data and return a token (GUID) to the client. The client would then create the JSONP request using the token.

Comment: (. Lovely .) I guess I can "explode" my request into a separate request for each of the nodes in the tree and initiate the sequence of requests with some kind of "transaction ID" that would be kept in the ASP.NET cache of the server. How unfortunate.

Comment: @JohnKällén - Here's another possibility if you want to send just 2 requessts. Use AJAX on the client to POST the large data to the server. The server will cache the data and return a token (GUID) to the client. The client would then create the JSONP request using the token.

Comment: I thought that cross domain AJAX wasn't possible? That's the whole reason why the application is written with JSONP in the first place.

Comment: @JohnKällén - You would simply have to setup the caching on the same domain that is serving the client. The JSONP server can request the data from that domain if necessary or the domain serving the client can proxy the request to the JSONP server. But since you didn't want to do too much extra work this may not be relevant.

Comment: Understood. In my scenario, I can only store script and html on the domain serving the client, but I'm not allowed any code executing on the server. I have full control over the server the JSONP service is hosted on.

Your first alternative seems to be the better choice given the circumstances.